# confidence intervall for the product of random variables

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval

Suppose $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $W_i\sim \text{Uniform}(-d,d)$ are independent random variables for $1 \le i \le p$ and $p$ is large.

Given $0\lt\alpha\lt 1$ and a number $c \gt 0$, I need to choose $d = d(p,\mu,\sigma,\alpha,c) \gt 0$ as large as possible such that

$$\Pr\left(S = |\sum_{i=1}^p X_iW_i | \lt c\right) \ge \alpha$$

In other words I want to estimate the confidence interval of $S$ as a function of $d$.

How can I do that?

EDIT: 
can you help at least to solve a simpler version of the problem? 
we set $\mu =0$ and $p$ is large number. We should be able to estimate $d$ with the central limit theorem

Comment: This is an interval for a random variable, not for a parameter, so is usually called a **prediction interval**

Comment: With difficulty. Even finding a closed-form for the pdf of $X W$ is a tough nut. How large is $p$? If it is large, it may be possible to appeal to the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the distribution of the sum, then take absolute value of that ... and relatively easy to check how well it works via Monte Carlo.

Comment: The question is unclear.  You can always choose $d=0$ and make $S=0$ identically, whence it trivially is less than $C$. Otherwise, you cannot guarantee that $S\lt C$ at all: there will be come chance $S\ge C$.  It seems that something may be missing, such as taking a probability of some event.

Comment: @whuber It would not be a Uniform distribution (or indeed a random variable) if $d = 0$. So, $d>0$ is given.

Comment: @wolfies Constants are random variables and arguably they can be included among the class of uniform distributions. But I'm happy to exclude the case $d=0$; that still leaves us having to guess what is intended.

Comment: He seems to basically want to approximate the cdf of $S$ or equivalently $P(S<c)$, as a function of parameter $d$, given $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: I made edits in an effort to clarify the question and make it answerable--please check that these reflect what you want to ask.  The remark about the "confidence interval" is still mysterious, though. I also added "as large as possible" to avoid the trivial answer that any sufficiently small $d$ will work.

Comment: @whuber perfect!

Comment: Is it possible center the sum (i.e. take $|\sum_i^p X_i W_i - E[\sum_i^p X_i W_i] |$)? This would make the excercise more straightforward (at least to me), even for small samples (the same would apply if it can be assumed that $\mu = 0$). If not, I think the excercise gets tougher (at least for me).

Comment: As initial solution $\mu=0$ is fine. But it will be accepted only if there is not a full solution